# Override FOSUserBUndle layout

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm installed and configured FOSUserBundle on my project (I'm using symfony 4). The installation is done without problem. 
I override FOSUserBundle templates, but same that layout.html.twig and base.html.twig are not overrided.

My layout.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My base.html.twig :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

The only FOSUserBundle is used.
Secondly, the symfony debug toolbar is disappeared.

FOSUserBundle overrided there :
templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle

On the folder I added all FOSUserBundle sub folders:
Security
Registration
Profile
....

[Template structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IosGC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have done it:

[image]

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>
        {% block title %}Admin panel{% endblock %}
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**layout.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'bundles/FOSUserBundle/base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% if app.request.hasPreviousSession %}
        {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div>
        {% block fos_user_content %}
        {% endblock fos_user_content %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Security/login.html.twig**

```
{% extends "bundles/FOSUserBundle/layout.html.twig" %}
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block title %}Sing in{% endblock %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h4 class="text-center">Sign in</h4>
        {% if error %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}

        <form method="post" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="_username" class="form-control" id="username" value="{{ last_username }}"
                       autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on">Remember
                    me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button name="_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Comment: where can we stock admin assets on symfony4 ?

Comment: in public directory :)